# Using jQuery snipe incorporated into a gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im playing around with [jQuery.snipe](http://rayfranco.github.io/jquery.snipe/), trying to get it to work with a few images in a gallery.

**In the HTML**
You have an image with a src, a "data-zoom" attribute, and an id.
You have thumbnails each with a src, a "data-zoom" attribute, and an id, contained within an unordered list.

**The JS pseudo code**
On click of each img in li a function is run. 
The function stores the src, the "data-zoom" attribute, and the id of the clicked image into corresponding variables.

It then changes the big images src, "data-zoom" attribute, and id to that in the variables.

The snipe() method is then run taking the id in the variable as the selector.

**The problem**
When a thumbnail is clicked the large image changes, and snipe works fine. When you then click on a different thumbnail, the large  picture changes but the image in the magnifying glass stays the same as the first image that was clicked. I have had a look through the snipe library and I cant see where there is an issue.

**My Code**

```
<body>
    <div id="photoGal">
        <img src="picSmall.jpg" data-zoom="pic.jpg" id="snipe" />
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs">
        <ul>
            <li><img id="snipe" style="max-height:10%; max-width:10%"  src="picSmall.jpg" data-zoom="pic.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img id="snipe2" style="max-height:10%; max-width:10%" src="pic2Small.jpg" data-zoom="pic2.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('li img').on("click" , function(){
    var source = $(this).attr('src');
    var dataSource = $(this).attr('data-zoom');
    var tag = $(this).attr('id');

     $('#photoGal img').attr("src", source);
     $('#photoGal img').attr("data-zoom", dataSource);
     $('#photoGal img').attr("id", tag);
     $('#'+tag).snipe();
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing the image from the page, and populating a new html() string with the variables.

**new code**

**HTML**

```
<div id="photoGal" >
<img src="pic.jpg" data-zoom="pic.jpg" id="snipe" style="max-height:40%; max-width:40%" />
</div>


    <ul>
    <li><img class="element isotope-item"    src="thumbs/pic.jpg" data-zoom="pic.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img class="element isotope-item"   src="thumbs/pic2.jpg" data-zoom="pic2.jpg"  /></li>
    <li><img class="element isotope-item"   src="thumbs/pic3.jpg" data-zoom="pic3.jpg"  /></li>
    </ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('li img').on("click" , function(){



    $('#photoGal img').remove();


    var source = $(this).attr('src');
    var dataSource = $(this).attr('data-zoom');
    var tag = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(s);

    $('#photoGal').html('<img style="max-height:40%; max-width:40%" src=" ' + source + '" data-zoom=" ' + dataSource + '" id="snipe" />');

     $('#snipe').snipe();
});
```